# My Windows XP in VirtualBox doesn't read any pendrive. Why and how can I fix it?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, virtualbox, usb-flash-drive

I have installed Windows XP in VirtualBox and basic operating system is Ubuntu.
In Windows XP, when I put any pendrive, it doesn't read that.
How can I fix this problem so that the pendrive can also be read in Windows XP?
Any command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the USB controller in the virtual machine properties.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual machine is just that, a virtual machine. It doesn't see your USB ports, it sees virtual USB ports. If your host allows it, you can enable USB passthrough to expose the USB pen drive to the virtual machine.

Comment: thank you for suggestion but you didn't tell me how to enable 
virual usb ports

Comment: The virtual USB ports are probably enabled, just not mapped to any real ports. The following article says USB redirection is not available in the free Virtualbox release. http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualbox-2-how-to-pass-through-usb-devices-to-guests-on-an-ubuntu-8.10-host

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, insert the USB stick in the host and share the pen drive in the Advanced sharing option.
Secondly, start your virtual box, and in the Devices option under USB, select the detected USB flash drive.
Check in the virtual box Mycomputer to verify that the USB is detected.